# SSRS display last 7th day date from today with date format May 7, 2018

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have tried this for Current month MonthName(Month(today())) and past 7th date as DateAdd(DateInterval.day,-8,Today()) but cannot combine both. 
Can i get total one expression to display May 7, 2018?

Answer (score 1):

If it helps other i figured the answer

=Format(Today.AddDays(-8), "MMMM dd,yyyy")